# Mandatory parameter for inner function

Tags: function, powershell

I'm stuck trying to figure out the best method for calling a function from a function and making parameters mandatory for both functions.  I've got the below so far, and things work because I know what cmdline params to specify.

I did find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382256/multiple-mandatory-parameter-sets) but I'm not sure how to use that with a function that calls a function.

**Edit:** added shorter code.  In the code, How would you make the ParamSet parameter `[string]$killserver` mandatory for both the parent function `main` and the child function `KillSwitch` so that if the function is run `main -nukejobs` Powershell prompts for the variable `$killserver`

**Edit 2:** worked out the prompting for the mandatory param `serverlist` and `datelist` but it appears now the child function doesn't write to host `"receive input from $serverlist and $datelist"`

**Edit 3:** corrected the `Switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName){` value for `RunMulti` and now things look good.

```
Function Main{
  [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true,DefaultParameterSetName="ViewOnly")]
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="KillSwitch")]
    [Switch]$NukeJobs,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="KillSwitch",
      HelpMessage="Enter ServerName to remove the scheduled reboot for, Check using main -viewonly")]
    [String]$killserver,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="RunMulti")]
    [switch]$RunMultiple,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="RunMulti")]
    [String]$serverlist,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="RunMulti")]
    [String]$datelist
  )

  Switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
    "KillSwitch" {
      KillSwitch -server $killserver
    } # end killswitch
    "RunMulti" {
      RunMulti -serverlist $serverlist -datelist $datelist
    } # end run multi
  } # end switch block
} # end main function

Function KillSwitch{
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]$server
  )

  "Removing previous scheduled reboot for $server"
} # end killswitch function

Function RunMulti {
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
      HelpMessage="Text file with server names to reboot, one per line!")]
    [string]$serverlist,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
      HelpMessage="Text file with date/times, one per line!")]
    [String]$datelist
  )

  "receive input from $serverlist and $datelist"
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand how `[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]` is not what you want. That is how you make parameters mandatory. Perhaps you have a shorter code sample that outlines your problem?

Comment: Modified code, added better example.

Comment: Based on your code when i run `main -NukeJobs` i get asked for the killserver parameter, are you not getting the same result?

Comment: The way you have it now with `main -nukejobs` PowerShell would prompt you for `$killserver`... so then if `killswitch` is called appropriately inside `main` there would never be a problem

Comment: Apologies, the problem is with `RunMultiple` because as the code sits, Powershell doesn't prompt for the parameters which are going to end up being file paths.

Comment: The way you have it coded it would not prompt you since you are already providing them? `RunMulti -serverlist $serverlist -datelist $datelist`

Comment: That is weird because `NukeJobs` prompts for `$KillServer` if the param is not given, and won't prompt if the param is given.  As a test, calling the `RunMulti` child function with no params given, I only get prompted for the main function's params.  Worse, running `RunMulti` alone prompts as desired!

Answer (score 0):

I found the mandatory parameters needed separate:

`[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="RunOnce")]` blocks.

For example, this won't work, even if `Mandatory=$true`

My guess is because it only applies to `[switch]`

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="RunOnce",
HelpMessage="Enter ServerName to schedule reboot for.")]
[switch]$RunOnce,
[string]$server,
[string]$date,
```

But this will work, causing Powershell to prompt for `$server` and `$date` when the `RunOnce` switch is given.

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName="RunOnce",
 HelpMessage="Enter ServerName to schedule reboot for.")]
 [switch]$RunOnce,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="RunOnce")]
 [string]$server,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="RunOnce")]
 [string]$date,
```